# XeLaTeX and Biber do not Produce a *.bbl File

Tags: bibliographies, xetex, biber

MiKTeX (updated); TeXworks
Used to do this a couple of months ago, now after PC and MiKTeX reinstall (Win7) bibliographies on old files seem not to be working any more. Read many similar questions, no help.

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{fontspec,xunicode,xltxtra}
    \usepackage[lithuanian]{babel}
    \setromanfont{Times New Roman}
    \usepackage[bibstyle=authortitle]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource[datatype=bibtex]{refs}

    \begin{document}
    \pagebreak

    Polish citation\footcite[21]{bogucka84}.
    Ukrainian citation\footcite[181]{блануца07}.

    \end{document}
```

For refs.bib I used this:

```
    @book {     bogucka84,
    author      = "Maria Bogucka",
    title       = "Gdańscy ludzie morza w XVI-XVIII w.",
    date        = "1984",
    publisher   = "Wydawnictwo Morskie",
    location    = "Gdańsk",
    }

    @book {     блануца07,
    author      = "Андрiй Блануца",
    title       = "Землельнi Володиння Волинцькоï шляхти в другiй половинi XVI см.",
    date        = "2007",
    publisher   = "Iнститут iсторiï Украïни НАН Украïнии",
    location    = "Киïв",
    }
```

Once I try XeLaTeX+Bibtex+XeLaTeX all but citations work. I come from humanities, so I guess I'm easily baffled by such things; nevertheless, baffled I am.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the extension for `refs`

```
\addbibresource[datatype=bibtex]{refs.bib}
```

## Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode,xltxtra}
\usepackage[lithuanian]{babel}
\setromanfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
    @book {     bogucka84,
author      = "Maria Bogucka",
title       = "Gdańscy ludzie morza w XVI-XVIII w.",
date        = "1984",
publisher   = "Wydawnictwo Morskie",
location    = "Gdańsk",
}

@book {     блануца07,
author      = "Андрiй Блануца",
title       = "Землельнi Володиння Волинцькоï шляхти в другiй половинi XVI см.",
date        = "2007",
publisher   = "Iнститут iсторiï Украïни НАН Украïнии",
location    = "Киïв",
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[bibstyle=authortitle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource[datatype=bibtex]{refs.bib}          %% here

\begin{document}
\pagebreak

Polish citation\footcite[21]{bogucka84}.
Ukrainian citation\footcite[181]{блануца07}.
\printbibliography          %% needed to print the references
\end{document}
```

Run `xelatex` `biber` and the `xelatex`. You get:

[image]

Also, please note that to actually print the references, it is necessary to put `\printbibliography`. Also, loading the `csquotes` package is recommended by `biblatex` in general. However, in this case it doesn't do much, because Lithuanian is still not supported both by `biblatex` and `csquotes` (Thanks to Enrico).

## Edit:

The error shown in comment below

> data source
>   `C:\Users\naglis\AppData\Local\Temp\par-6e61676c6973\cache-01bc9c9677f4177400d267‌​bb148325ab7a8a2575\inc\lib/Biber/LaTeX/recode_data.xml`
>   not found in .

This seems to be a case of broken biber due to corrupt binary cache. From biber manual (page32, section 4), a screen shot:

[image]

Please read section 4.1 also. The essence is

Whenever you update to a new binary, biber will create its binary cache afresh. If the process is killed during this first run, then binary cache won't be properly created resulting in a broken biber. That is the error you are getting.

## Solution

**Delete** the directory `C:\Users\naglis\AppData\Local\Temp\par-6e61676c6973` completely and re-run biber. This first run will take some time, hence be patient.

Comment: You should also be mentioned that `\printbibliography` is necessary for actually printing the references. Loading the `csquotes` package is recommended.

Comment: Well, it's recommended by `biblatex` in general. However, in this case it doesn't do much, because Lithuanian is still not supported both by `biblatex` and `csquotes`. :(

Comment: Nope, no help. Unless I am doing something wrong when runing Bibtex and not Biber. Used to work that way.

Comment: @HarishKumar 

data source C:\Users\naglis\AppData\Local\Temp\par-6e61676c6973\cache-01bc9c9677f4177400d267bb148325ab7a8a2575\inc\lib/Biber/LaTeX/recode_data.xml not found in .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Just check if after compilation .bcf file is generated or not.

If yes.......make sure biber.exe is present in c:/programfiles/Miketex2.9/miketex/bin folder

now go to command promt,   cd to your folder & run the following command:

biber    yourfile.bcf

Now check if .bbl file is generated & contains something.
Finally compile your tex file with (whichever applicable) Xelatex or Pdflatex  only.