# "Empty bibliography"

Tags: biblatex, miktex

For some reason, BibLaTeX doesn't work. Here's my minimal example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@book{doe13,
    address    = {City},
    title      = {A nice title},
    shorttitle = {Short title},
    publisher  = {Publisher},
    author     = {Doe, John},
    year       = {2013}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}

Hello. \cite{doe13}.

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I am using MiKTeX 2.9 32-bit.

When I run `pdflatex sample.tex`, I get the following warings:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'doe13' on page 1 undefined on input line 23.
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 27.
```

The generated PDF contains

> Hello. [doe13 ].

and the page number, nothing else. There's no bibliography.

Running `biber sample` gives me the following message:

```
> biber sample
INFO - This is Biber 1.5
INFO - Logfile is 'sample.blg'
data source C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Temp\par-5061756c\cache-890efc00b3ca6b77
5c7d44a325c1349fb2a3a3bd\inc\lib/Biber/LaTeX/recode_data.xml not found in .
```

Like [Alan Munn stated](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140790/6884), the warning in `biber` can be fixed by removing the entire directory `C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Temp\par-5061756c`. After that, new warnings occur, the `pdflatex` warnings are the same as well as the resulting PDF.

```
> biber sample
INFO - This is Biber 1.5
INFO - Logfile is 'sample.blg'
INFO - Reading 'sample.bcf'
WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 2.5, expected version 2.3
INFO - Using all citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'refs.bib' for section 0
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'refs.bib'
```

What else can I do?

Comment: Probably this is the problem: [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852).  You need to run `pdflatex`, `biber`, and then `pdflatex` twice more.

Comment: I don't get a question mark, so this question doesn't help me. I get `[doe13 ]` instead. I updated the question for clarification.

Comment: Did you run `pdflatex`, `biber`, `pdflatex` and `pdflatex` though? How do you compile your documents?

Comment: I suspect you're only running `pdflatex`. You need to follow the full run sequence suggested by moewe. Another potential explanation for your problem is that you may be mistakenly running `bibtex` instead of `biber`. Tell us which LaTeX editor/IDE you're using and which OS you're using. `biber` may not be already set up in it, in which case people here can tell you how to do that.

Comment: I am not using any IDE. My editor is Sublime Text 2. The file is UTF-8 with Unix line endings. I already tried to run `pdflatex sample.tex`, `biber sample`, `pdflatex sample.tex` and `pdflatex sample.tex` from a cmd prompt. They all run without problems, but pdflatex always returns the warning mentioned in the question and the resulting PDF is always the same.

Comment: I added the output of biber to the question.

Comment: The fact that you get the citation key instead of a question mark is just the difference between `biblatex` and `natbib`. The error you are getting is a well known issue with `biber` that is easily fixed.  See [XeLaTeX and Biber do not Produce a \*.bbl File](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/93995) for a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the `biber` log it seems that `biber` and `biblatex` are out of sync. An upgrade to the most recent version of `biber` should fix the issue.

Answer (score 22):

The error you are getting is a well known issue with `biber`. It creates binaries in a cache folder, and sometimes that can get corrupted.  In order to solve the problem, you need to manually delete the cache folders.  They are located in different places on different platforms:

- `/var/folders/*/*/*/` (OSX, local GUI login shell)
- `/var/tmp/` (OSX (remote ssh login shell), Unix)
- `/tmp/` (Linux)
- `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Temp` (Windows/Cyg-
  win)
- `C:\Windows\Temp` (Windows)
- `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp` (Windows)

So in your case you can delete the folders inside `C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Temp`, and then recompile your document with `pdflatex`, `biber`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't resolve my problem. Sorry. It changed the warnings in `biber` but didn't change the warnings in `pdflatex`. I updated the question with the new warnings.

Comment: Nevertheless +1 for the precise answer. :)

Comment: One can find out the cache folder using `biber --cache`. This can also be passed to rm: `rm -rf \`biber --cache\``.

Comment: Oh my god, lifesaver! I literally put the last word in my PhD thesis and suddenly the bibliography stops working! This fixed it.

Comment: Super, I was going mad