# Biber: empty bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I have the same problem [as](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140701/empty-bibliography), but none of the answers works for me.

I'm using pdfTeX 3.14, Biber 2.7, BibLatex 3.7. I've reinstalled these packages, cleared Biber cache, deleted .bbl file. The same result:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'doe13' on page 1 undefined on input line 24.
LateX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 28.
```

MWE (literally the same at the issue mentioned below):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@book{doe13,
    address    = {City},
    title      = {A nice title},
    shorttitle = {Short title},
    publisher  = {Publisher},
    author     = {Doe, John},
    year       = {2013}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}

Hello. \cite{doe13}.

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you please post a MWE so that we can see your issue?

Comment: Please run [this example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber#Separate_Bibliographies_by_Entry_Type). Do you succeed? If not, please show the `blg` file. Or show the `blg`  file of the example you just included.

Comment: Recompile with TeX -> Biber -> TeX -> TeX and report any errors from the `.log`. What does the `.blg` say?

Comment: Your MWE works brilliantly when compiled properly with `pdlfatex`, `biber`, `pdflatex`, `pdlfatex`, see [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864). See also [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'm using R Studio. Is the problem in editor?

Comment: How do you compile TeX documents in R Studio? You certainly need your editor to run Biber for you? If you are not using R in your document, you might want to use an other editor (e.g. one from the list in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71565/35864 https://texblog.org/2013/08/20/rknitr-automatic-bibliography-generation-with-biblatex-in-rstudio/ https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200655446-Please-add-support-for-biber-and-package-download-locations-

Comment: So while in theory it is possible to run Biber from within RStudio (probably that is easiest with `latexmk`), I suggest you use another editor that is more TeX-specific if you don't write R code in your TeX document. You can of course also compile your document from the command line directly.

Comment: By the way, some feedback on the linked wikipage would be cool, Amir.

Comment: It seems like I've figured out that the problem was in R Studio: the .bbl file generated with it was empty. I installed TexMaker, enabled Biber in it and generated bibliography with it, and that worked. @moewe Thanks for the advice!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP didn't run `biber`.

Comment: @TeXnician Wouldn't it be better to mark as duplicate for Question mark instead of citation number?